# How to prohibit save preferences after push back button

Tags: android, preference

I have PreferenceActivity that have button to confirm this preferences after changes. But when i push back or home button this preferences is also save. How can i change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

you can over write `onPause()` to cancel the save action.you should know the lifecyle about the Activity android do right thing in the right method

Answer (score 0):

Override onStop method, and there display the dialog, and on no confirmation, reset prefernce fields to initial values, and finish activity.